# Kendo Grid not able to export to excel

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In this example I am creating the html and then converting the table to a kendo grid. I also want to be able to export the grid into a excel file. I am using the `saveAsExcel` method but nothing happens. When I do it in my system I just get the header row and no tbody data.

https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevitt/UKUZITiC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saveToExcel method requires jszip. If you add this to your dojo I believe it then works:

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know why it works in your system with just the header row. Perhaps you have a version of jszip on your page but it's an older version?